# How to give html tag id a unique id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If I'm appending multiple items in javascript like this:

```
                 data.context = $('<button class="btn btn-primary"/>').text('Upload')
                   .appendTo('#fileTableId')
                   .click(function () {
                       $(this).replaceWith($('<p id="aa"/>').text('Uploading...'));
                       data.submit();
                   });
```

How can I give each that is being replacedWith p tag a unique id if for example x++ is what I want to set it to.

```
     var x = 0
     '<p id = "'x'" /> 

     x++;
```

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something, but why not just concatenate the string? `'<p id="' + x + '" />'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.prop` to set the `id` property:

```
$(this).replaceWith($('<p>').prop('id', x).text('Uploading...'));
data.submit();
```